# Wacom tablet Python interface

Tags: python, interface, wacom

If possible I want to catch pressure sensitive input from a Wacom tablet in Python. Are there any Python libraries available that can do this?

Answer (score 4):

You could perhaps take a look at the [software](http://www.alexmac.cc/tablet-apps/tablet-apps-0.3.1.tar.bz2) described [here](http://www.alexmac.cc/tablet-apps/). It is a gnome applet, written in Python.

From the web site:

"The gnome wacom applet is a small gnome panel applet that shows how much pressure is being applied to your wacom tablet by the current device. Clicking on the panel icon brings up a dialog allowing you to select a different device and check what pressure and tilt information is being recieved from it. This dialog also contains a small drawing test area to give your pen a quick test."

[Google is your friend](http://www.google.com/search?q=wacom+tablet+python)

Answer (score 3):

Use PySide (wrapper for QT)'s QTabletEvent: http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QTabletEvent.html#PySide.QtGui.QTabletEvent

Answer (score 2):

For Mac OS X:

https://bitbucket.org/AnomalousUnderdog/pythonmactabletlib

> A small Python library to allow Python scripts to access pen tablet
>   input data in Mac OS X.
>
> The library exists as plain C code compiled as a dynamic
>   library/shared object. It interfaces with the Mac OS X's API to get
>   data on pen tablet input.
>
> Then, Python scripts can use ctypes to get the data.

Send me a message if you have any problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

Pressure data is available in [PyGObject to access Gtk+ 3](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) on multiple platforms, though "Windows users may still want to keep using PyGTK until more convenient installers are published." [[citation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyGtk)] Motion event objects generated by pressure sensitive devices will carry pressure data.